# why does react admin send multiple requests for the same resource list without any interaction

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com

Why does react admin send multiple requests for the same resource list without any interaction? and is it ok?

[image: network tab showing multiple requests are been fired for the same resource]

Comment: Those seem to be requests that are all returning different data based on the size of the returned data. Look at the headers of those requests and make sure the url and query string are actually the same.

Comment: Yeah but it is all handled by react admin it seems that filter detection happen later then it send other requests

Comment: I guess I'd have to see more of the code to try to understand what is going on. Most times it's for reasons of just how react works. If you update state of a component that makes a request but don't handle the loading state you could possibly get that result. I could take a look if you want to post some more details of what you're trying to do.